# Why there is a hyphen in this sentence

Tags: punctuation

I am listening to Rihanna's song [Stay ft](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JF8BRvqGCNs&index=3&list=PLmayP0qOPHaKM--8oQpcCAb5PgKjdGVkR)

and this is the lyrics

http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/rihanna/stay.html

I found this sentence

> It's not just something you take–it's given

Could you tell me please why there is a hyphen there?

Comment: It is an [***en dash***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash). The function is different from a hyphen.

Comment: It's probably supposed to have been an ***em dash***.

Comment: Unless you're a typography freak, dashes and hyphens are the same thing - see e.g. the ASCII character set, or your keyboard.  As for the meaning, it's generally a continued thought, with less connection between the parts than would be indicated by a comma.

Comment: @jamesqf They may be the same character (unless they are elongated), but they serve [completely different purposes](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/when-should-i-use-an-em-dash-an-en-dash-and-a-hyphen) and it is useful to refer to them by their appropriate terms... saying that they're the same thing is a disservice to the people here trying to learn English.

Comment: @Catija: Not at all.  Complicating something that's basically simple with overly-pedantic names (which probably 99% of native speakers wouldn't understand) is the disservice.

Answer (score 2):

It's not just something you take - it's given.

It's a dash, not a hyphen. A hyphen is used  between the parts of a compound word such as well-to-do.

The sentence in question consists of two parts (clauses). A dash has been used to separate these closely related parts of the sentence. In other words, you may say that a dash has been used to introduce a further related statement.

Answer (score 0):

The punctuation choice is not ideal. Hyphens are generally for tying together compound words, like "ex-boyfriend" or "forty-year-old."

What the writer of the lyrics meant to use was a dash: a punctuation mark that signifies emphasis or an interruption.

Listening to the song, I would argue that a comma would've been more appropriate. "It's given" is an immediate and intuitive follow-up to "it's not just something you take," rather than an aside.

Comment: I believe azlyrics.com is a wiki of sorts, and I don't think there's any way to know whether the original has a dash, hyphen, or comma. Also, the O.P. says _hyphen_ in the question, but it's clearly  a dash in the quote.